# R Shiny Openstreetmaps - lock map within a set of upper and lower bounds

Tags: r, openstreetmap, shiny

I am using Openstreetmaps with R/Shiny. I am trying to restrict map display to a given range of coordinates, i.e.`xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax` so that the users of the map won't be able to look other parts of the world other than the ones that are within the range.

I've made some research about it, but it hasn't been possible to find an answer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to this github issue:

https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/486

you should be able to specify max bounds and min/max zoom levels with code like this

```
myMap <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 11)) %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
  setView( lng = -87.567215
           , lat = 41.822582
           , zoom = 11 ) %>%
  setMaxBounds( lng1 = -87.94011
                , lat1 = 41.64454
                , lng2 = -87.52414
                , lat2 = 42.02304 )
```